# Minify js with async in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bundling-and-minification

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application and use Bundler & Minifier to minify js code. When I try to add a `.js` file with async\await operation:

```
updatePermissionsConnection.onclose(
    async () => {
         await startUpdatePermissionsConnection();
    });
```

I get a lot of errors:

> Error 0   Expected ')': =>
>   Error 0   Expected ';'
>   Error 0   Expected expression: )
>   Error 0   Expected ')': =>
>   Error 0   Expected ';'
>   Error 0   Expected expression: )

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

1. This is a known issue. Although this [commit](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/commit/46134c81f5817aea2df50ba09f61b68db853f787) shows BuildBundlerMinifier should fix that problem, it has not yet supported `async/await`. See [#311](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/311) and [#379](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/379).
2. Actually, BuildBundlerMinifier **parses JavaScript using C#** (see [NUglify/JavaScript](https://github.com/xoofx/NUglify/tree/a16eebaecf7ba514ec6be4fc9700e4f7ef3edf10/src/NUglify/JavaScript)). However, JavaScript itself evolves really fast (see [tc39/proposals](https://github.com/tc39/proposals)). That's why a 3rd party .NET library cannot support the new JavaScript feature in time. As a result, nowadays people tend to migrate their toolchain to Node.js platform to support the latest JavaScript feature.
3. Usually, even if `BuildBundlerMinifier` doesn't support the latest JavaScript feature, it won't be a problem. Because some browsers won't support the latest features too. For example, people won't use `async/await` directly in browser because it will throw on IE11 (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Browser_compatibility)). So an quick and dirty fix is to use the old `Promise` API instead of using `async/await` within Browser directly.
4. A much more robust way is to use the Node.js platform. For example, [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) /Gulp / .... Microsoft has provide a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli#consume-bundleconfigjson-from-gulp) that consumes `bundleconfig.json` using Gulp. It would be easy to migrate the tool chain.

Comment: Using .Net 5, the bundler still doesn't support async/await but option number 3 did the trick for me.